# Datalist in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, simple-form

A really noob question, but i try with different options and I dont get it.

I Have a form for a new "Cancha" and a field that references to "Mmpp", In the field mmpp_id i need to see a list with the differents kinds of "Mmpp" (already created some options), right now if I put for example "1" i get Mmpp:0x00007f7fb1600378 in the show, Already change the show to <%= @cancha.mmpp.nombre %> and I get exactly what I want in the show, but the problem is in the form I need a list to pick.
Thanks in advance

```
    <%= form.text_field :mmpp_id, class: 'form-control' %>
```

```
create_table "canchas", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "nombre"
    t.string "descripcion"
    t.integer "capacidad"
    t.boolean "operativa"
    t.bigint "mmpp_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["mmpp_id"], name: "index_canchas_on_mmpp_id"
```

```
create_table "mmpps", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "nombre"
    t.string "descripcion"
    t.integer "densidad"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

Comment: Use a [`select_tag`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) for that, you can select the id and name from all records in mmpps table. You might also want to rename your columns to English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was simpler and with the same html classes of the other inputs, form.select work but give some style problems.

```
<%= f.association :mmpp_id, label_method: :nombre, value_method: :id %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will create a dropdown

```
<%= form.select :mmpp_id, Mmpp.all.map { |r| [r.nombre, r.id] } %>
```